# AppCompatActivity ActionbarDrawerToggle

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently changed one of my activity class from inheriting ActionbarActivity(because this class is now obsolete in new android version) to AppCompatActivity. I could specify the icon i want the navigation drawer to use before the change, but after the new ActionBarDrawerToggle doesn't allow that.

I was able to implement this and display the drawer icon, the issue I'm having now is how to change the color of the icon(the three lines icon) from black to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors of the items in the toolbar depend on the theme.

If you are using `Theme.AppCompat` (the dark theme) the icons will be white. If you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` the icons will be dark. There is also `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

[More about using](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) the `appcompat` library.

This is an example for using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (Light theme with dark action bar and white icons in the actionbar)

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the ActionBarDrawerToggle can be changed to any colour you want.
Please see an example below:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- ActionBarDrawerToggle colour -->
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerToggle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerToggle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@color/my_super_colour</item>
    </style>

    <color name="my_super_colour">#00ff00</color>

</resources>
```